# $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] not returning full URL

Tags: php, referrer, http-referer

I'm trying to apply a quick patch to address an issue with an extension we're using. As a result, please pardon this "bandaid-like" fix that I'm requesting assistance with. This is merely an effort to fix an issue in about 20 minutes or less and schedule in a permanent fix for later in the week.

That being said, I am struggling with grabbing a value that I would expect with using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]. Our URL is somewhat odd at the moment. A URL example is below...:

```
http://domain.com/custom-wheels-performance-tires/custom-wheels.html#/custom-wheels-performance-tires/custom-wheels.html?wheel_diameter=2663
```

When using $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], the value I'm getting (for the URL above) is:

```
http://domain.com/custom-wheels-performance-tires/custom-wheels.html
```

Evidently, it is being cut off at the # in the URL. Common sense would be to remove that from the URL, but I'm going to have to dig into someone else's code to do that and it exceeds the time allocated for this patch. Is there a way to get the full URL (even if it isn't $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])?

I appreciate any and all assistance!

Comment: $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is 100% UNRELIABLE

Comment: NO, the `fragment` (`#`) is _never_ sent to the server in the first place. If you _need_ it... it would require some javascript-voodoo to add it to a request (i.e: no simple links anymore).

Comment: BTW: for browsers that support it, [actually pushing real urls to the history is preferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), let's hope that fragment use dies out.

Comment: Thank you Wrikken for identifying the issue! I very well may have to do this via Javascript, unless I can find out why the URL is being formed in such a messy way quickly. In any case, it's much appreciated that you assisted me so quickly and that you didn't down-vote me for such a stupid question. :-)

Comment: i think the use of HTTP_REFERER should be more of an issue than the fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way URL's are handled by browsers, the server never receives anything past the hash fragment identifier (#). The fragment is intended to be used by the browser to scroll a page to an anchor.

However, It is possible to utilize JavaScript to get the fragment, and send it to the browser.